# Record Voip Calls

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-mediarecorder

Is it possible to record Voip calls in Android? I tried using the below options for **MediaRecorder.AudioSource**
VOICE_DOWNLINK
VOICE_UPLINK
VOICE_CALL[ UPLINK + DOWNLINK]
VOICE_COMMUNICATION
**Case 1:** If I start recording before making the Voip call, then the recipient is not able to hear my voice. Also after recording I can hear only my voice. This suggests that the microphone is blocked by my app.
**Case 2:** If I try to record during Voip session then I get `E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -38` error.

I don't have any problem recording phone calls. Another thing which I observed is in ***Kitkat*** the error doesn't occur during Voip session and recording is successful but I am unable to hear recipient voice. The problem arises in ***Lollipop***. I haven't tested on prior ***Kitkat*** versions.

Comment: Which Voip call u insterested to record?

Comment: Did you find any solution? Please share your experience

Comment: @NaveedAhmad: Unfortunately, I haven't found a proper solution till date

Comment: @curious_coder I posted a question, let see if someone give an response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354039/voip-call-recording

Comment: VoIP calls cannot be recorded in android as the microphone will be in use as you have gathered in your testing. For normal Phone calls microphone is not in use.

Comment: @SrihariKaranth There are many Whatsapp call recorder apps out there, how can they work then?
Did anyone find a solution to this?

Comment: @TalMantelmakher, i am sure that doesn't work in most mobiles. definitely not in samsung, pixel, one+ phones. have you tried?