# VOIP Call Recording

Tags: android, whatsapp, call-recording, voip-android

I am working on a project to record VOIP calls in android, I didn't found any solution for that, there are lot of apps which support VOIP recordings on phones. I am unable to find any tutorial and help. [Cube Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.catalinagroup.callrecorder) is one of the app which is giving this feature but I can't figure out how to do it. 
I was tested it by starting recording by using android **MediaRecorder** then initiated whatsapp call, so other person was unable to listen my voice. after call, I checked only my voice were saved in the recording.

As a research I reverse engineered some apks, I found they are using Accessibility permissions in the apk.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
```

I don't know what things I need to understand how  can I get to know that to VOIP call is coming and going just like a **BroadcastReceiver**.

Then, I will understand how can I record the calls.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I am working on a similar app right now, and can't seem to find any way of doing this.

Comment: No buddy Still not

Comment: @NaveedAhmad any solution for this?

Comment: @Deepak Still the answer is a mystery, I find some clues but still not the exact solution yet. Can we contact on email? to work in coordination, if we solve this mystery we can share here

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet guys....

Comment: @NaveedAhmad : have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer for this

First grant accessiblity permission and have this class

```
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;

public class AccessAudio extends AccessibilityService {
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
Log.d("","gf");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();

        AccessibilityServiceInfo accessibilityServiceInfo = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        accessibilityServiceInfo.flags = 1;
        accessibilityServiceInfo.eventTypes = -1;
        accessibilityServiceInfo.feedbackType = 16;
        setServiceInfo(accessibilityServiceInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }
}
```

After that you can use

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(AudioSavePathInDevice.getPath());
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        mediaRecorder.start();
```

Comment: may u please explain this a little bit better  @akkmastr ?

Comment: @akkmastr : can you share the full code of this?